# Very low volume for system beeps in VMware Player and VMware Workstation

Tags: vmware-workstation, vmware-player

The system beeps work in my VMware guests, but their volume is very very low, while all other sounds (e.g. WAV) are quite loud resp. for those sounds I can adjust the volume with the Windows sound mixer sliders. But there's no slider for the system beeps.
How do I get the system beeps louder?

Remark: I use e.g. in Excel `Declare Function Beep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwFreq As Long, ByVal dwDuration As Long) As Long` to generate the system beeps. In VMware Player and VMware Worktation I've configured `mks.noBeep = "FALSE"`.

Comment: I'm afraid the only solution is to record all those nice system beeps (a separate sound file for each frequency and duration needed) and then to use ```Declare Function sndPlaySound Lib "winmm.dll" Alias "sndPlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszSoundName As String, ByVal uFlags As Long) As Long``` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've done many more tests (also with VirtualBox) and I've come to the conclusion, that the good old system beeps, where you simply can specify the frequency and duration of the sound to be generated, unfortunately don't work in a VM guest, even not if you use a USB audio adapter, which is directly connected to the VM guest. So I recorded all required system beeps as WAV files and use `Declare Function sndPlaySound Lib "winmm.dll" Alias "sndPlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszSoundName As String, ByVal uFlags As Long) As Long` to play them. This is unfortunately quite circuitous and tedious, especially if you have many different system beeps, but it works.

PS: Another problem now is the audio delay that a VM guest always has. But here the workaround is to connect a USB audio adapter directly to the VM guest.